# OperationContext is null after async method using .net 4.6.2

Tags: c#, wcf, operationcontext

I have a problem with `OperationContext` getting null after an **async** operation is called (and my threadid changes).

I know this is a know issue and I've gone threw some StackOverflow questions regarding the issue.

In `.net 4.6.2` there is a fix for the issue as you can read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/).

> **OperationContext.Current Async Improvements**
>
> WCF now has the ability to
>   include OperationContext.Current with ExecutionContext so that the
>   OperationContext flows through asynchronous continuations. With this
>   improvement, WCF allows CurrentContext to propagate from one thread to
>   another thread. This means that even if there’s a context switch
>   between calls to OperationContext.Current, it’s value will flow
>   correctly throughout the execution of the method.

Is there anything special I need to do in order to get this supported on my end? I'm using VS 2013, updated the framework to `4.6.2` and installed the dev-pack.
I've changed my project to use `Framework 4.6.2` and I still get a null `OperationContext` after an async call.

Comment: Does this fix WebOperationContext too?

Answer (score 5):

Per the answer from Tomasz, make sure the following is in your app config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="wcf:disableOperationContextAsyncFlow" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

For more information take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/403 where MS acknowledges that this is, in fact, a breaking change. Seems like this could easily break a lot applications out in the field.

Comment: Thanks for helping on StackOverflow. But it seems like the comment by Tomasz does not exist anymore (or it has always been an answer). If you want to add a detail to an existing answer then you should write a comment to that answer. If you want to make an answer, then make sure that all needed information is in there (the other answer might disappear one way or another). Giving credit to the authour is of course a good idea. If your addition is not worth making your own answer or not a noticeably better one, then comment.

Comment: I am using 4.6.2 and my OperationContext is null. WCF. Testing with debugging in VS 2017, so IISExpress. This setting isn't helping either way.

Answer (score 1):

After installing KB4013429 operation context async flow is disabled by default. To enable it (and use functionality fixed in 4.6.2) you need to set wcf:disableOperationContextAsyncFlow flag to "false" in your app config. (I haven't found any information about this flag, discovered it while fixing issue with incorrect propagation of OperationContext).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you're describing managed to make it into .NET 4.6.2 release and we're aware of it.  In fact, we're in the process of rolling out a fix for this and I'm expecting it to be publicly available within the next couple of months.

For now the known workarounds are to revert to 4.6.1 version of the framework or to do something similar to this:

```
OperationContext ocx = OperationContext.Current;

using (new OperationContextScope(OperationContext.Current))
    {
        OperationContext.Current = new OperationContext(ocx.Channel);
        // ...
    }
```

Please let us know if you have further questions or comments.

Comment: No :(  However, I'm expecting a patch for Win10 available soon.  The patch for downlevel OS' will take longer to be deployed.